How to Create and Update Global Value Set and Picklists by APEX?
I Want to create Global Value Set and Picklists via apex, gone through some internet sources but didn't get any of them working for me.
Any kind of help is appreciated.
Thank You

Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please take the time to read How to Ask and perhaps take the [tour]. Requests for help that do not include specifics for your problem and evidence of what you have tried and where you are stuck are unlikely to get much attention. It also looks like there are plenty of explanations out there around how this can be successfully achieved. If you disagree with the closure of your question, feel free to re-open it, but make sure to [edit] it to include clear detail as to why you cannot use the metadata or REST APIs and where you got stuck.
